# Did the default Cygwin installation directory change to C:\tools\cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, chocolatey

The [docs say](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.c) it's `C:\cygwin`, but I observe `C:\tools\cygwin`.

I'm testing the installation with Chocolatey, but I might have had a previous Cygwin installation and don't remember if I changed the default location. I tried to remove all occurrences of `C:\tools` in the registry but so far the reinstallation insists on installing there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Chocolatey sets this location](https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-coreteampackages/blob/master/automatic/cygwin/tools/chocolateyInstall.ps1):

```
$cygwin_root = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Cygwin\setup' -ea 0).rootdir
if (!$cygwin_root) {
    $cygwin_root = if ($pp.InstallDir) { $pp.InstallDir } else { "$toolsLocation\cygwin" }
} else { Write-Host 'Existing installation detected, ignoring InstallDir argument' }
```

But what's the reason for not using the default location?

Comment: Maybe to not overlap with an standard Cygwin installation, if exist ? For 64bit the default  is `c:\Cygwin64`

Comment: @matzeri The code seems to indicate the opposite intention: `Existing installation detected, ignoring InstallDir argument`